# Построить несколько графиков jfrrechart

Tags: java, graph

Здравствуйте, возникла следующая проблема.
Мне нужно построить приблизительный фазовый портрет.
Для построения кривых использую библиотеку jfreechart, как строить несколько кривых сразу и построить координатную ось с центром (0;0) и оставить камеру не ней ?
Допустим, я перед добавлением точек проверяй их на граничные значения, но можно ли установить камеру на центре, с границами скажем X(-10;10) Y(-5;5).

Спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Очень сложно понять, что вам надо, без вашего кода и скринов/изображений. Отредактируйте и дополните, пожалуйста, ваш вопрос, чтобы вам могли помочь.

Comment: Там код особо не нужен) Я просто строю изоклины, записываю в листы точки (x;y). Теперь хочу например построить 50 кривых. Вопрос состоит в чем. 1) С помощью какой библиотеки лучше всего и (быстрее(!)) их построить (я уже перепробовал несколько вариантов, но связи с нехваткой опыта работы с такими библиотеками, ничего толкового не придумал). 2) Как вывести на экран только точки, которые попадут в промежуток X є [10;-10] Y є  [5;-5],а то получается, что координатная сетка строится относительно максимального Y и Х. Спасибо, за ответ!

Comment: Ответ на ваш вопрос дать не могу, но могу дать пару замечаний. JFreeChart не самая легкая библиотека, но довольно неплохая и  полезная. Когда мне требовалось строить более 1000 сплайнов и двигать их точки, то замечались тормоза, в таком случае я перевёл графики на отрисовку на OpenGL (библиотека JOGL). На ваш второй вопрос в комментарии лучше смотрите особенности JFreeChart.